# Setting the custom isolation levels for DataSourceTransactionManager

Tags: spring, transactions, isolation-level, transactionmanager

How to enable custom isolation levels for the DataSourceTransactionManager?

I have the following in my spring configuration file.

```
<bean id="transactionManager"class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataDource"/>    
</bean>

<bean id="myTransactionProxy" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean" abstract="true" lazy-init="false" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
  <property name="transactionManager">
     <ref bean="transactionManager" /> 
  </property>
  <property name="transactionAttributes">
     <props>
        <prop key="cancel">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED,timeout_25,-Exception</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```

But when I try to run it, it gives me the following error.

```
org.springframework.transaction.InvalidIsolationLevelException: JtaTransactionManager does not support custom isolation levels by default - switch 'allowCustomIsolationLevels' to 'true'
```

I am not using the JtaTransactionManager, why I got a warning about this?
And how do I enable the custom isolation level for the DataSourceTransactionManager? In documentation, it was mentioned that this class would support the custom isolation levels, but I didn't find any examples online. Most of it are only for the JtaTransactionManager. Just wonder if anyone can help me out for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`TransactionManager` can be DataSourceTransactionManager or JtaTransactionManager or JpaTransactionManager, what ever may be, we can configure the Isolation Level using `@Transactional` annotation.

If the context file is enabled with `<tx:annotation-driven />` which supports the annotations placed on the DAO or Service level, it recognizes the Transaction.

`isolation` attribute of `@Transactional` will allow you to configure them.

`@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)`
`public void save(Country country) {
  // do some operations
}`

reference : [Isolation levels](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Isolation.html), [Transactional](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)

I'm not sure with configuring xml file

Hope this Helps. :)